# mssql to mysql conversion tool

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a mssql database dump file (.sql) that was exported from SQL Management Studio.
It contains database scheme with all data, and also some Store Procedures. 
Now I need to import that tables into MySql database, but without store procedures, i.e. import all table's and it's content.
Is that possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: You don't need a .sql script.  The SQL Server Import/Export Wizard can do this for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms140052(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL Workbench to import the data without the stored procedures. Here is a link with information about this.

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/

You might have to initially load the .sql file into MSSQL in order to import the data. This is because it might not be possible to migrate the data from the .sql file.